# How to make dynamic component inside other (not main) Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-part-3-starting-pogqj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

So this is completed version of a simple note app where each time you write something, a new component is created outside dynamically in a new component with a single add button click.

My question is, I want the new created dynamic component (every time I click on add button), I want it to appear inside the CreateArea component (below it for instance). not a whole different component by itself.

Comment: trying to move notes inside createArea component ?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (SO) (and all of Stack Exchange (SE)) *must be* self-contained. The goal of SO/SE is to create a repository of questions and answers which are valuable to *future* visitors. Questions which *require* information from off-site/off-page resources are useless once those resources change or die. Any questions where such a resource is *required* to understand the question should be closed as "needs details of clarity", or other appropriate reason. Only *information (e.g. code) **in the question itself*** is considered. A link can be used for context, but not relied upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-part-3-completed-forked-df1whq?file=/src/components/App.jsx

To solve this you wrap your CreateArea component around the results of the .map function and then use props.children to inject the children of the JSX component into your CreateArea function.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote}>
        {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
          return (
            <Note
              key={index}
              id={index}
              title={noteItem.title}
              content={noteItem.content}
              onDelete={deleteNote}
            />
          );
        })}
      </CreateArea>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreateArea(props) {
  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setNote((prevNote) => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }

  function submitNote(event) {
    props.onAdd(note);
    setNote({
      title: "",
      content: ""
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          name="title"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.title}
          placeholder="Title"
        />
        <textarea
          name="content"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows="3"
        />
        <button onClick={submitNote}>Add</button>
      </form>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

Note: Visually this looks almost the same but you will see that your notes are now inside the div if you go to inspect and look at your document structure.